# Count the number of times a command appears in the enumerate environment

Tags: macros, lists, expl3

I am trying to create a mechanism to know whether or not the number of
times a command is repeated in an `enumerate` environment is present.

As an example, using the `\dummy` command, this would be a valid entry:

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Level 1 \dummy{1} OK
  \item Level 1 \dummy{2} OK
\end{enumerate}
```

And an invalid entry would be:

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Level 1 \dummy{1} OK
  \item Level 1 NO dummy here.
\end{enumerate}
```

As the environment can be nested, a valid entry can take the following
form:

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Level 1 \dummy{1} OK
  \item Level 1 NO dummy here, dummy in next level
    \begin{enumerate}
      % Start level 2
      \item Level 2 \dummy{2} OK
      \item Level 2 NO dummy here, dummy in next level
        \begin{enumerate}
          % Start level 3
          \item Level 3 \dummy{3} OK
          \item Level 3 NO dummy here, dummy in next level
            \begin{enumerate}
              % Start level 4
              \item Level 4 \dummy{4} OK
              \item Level 4 \dummy{5} OK
            \end{enumerate}
          \item Level 3 \dummy{6} OK
        \end{enumerate}
      \item Level 2 \dummy{7} OK
    \end{enumerate}
  \item Level 1 \dummy{8} OK
\end{enumerate}
```

With the next MWE I would expect the final output to be `{ TRUE }`

```
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
% Copy macros
\cs_new_eq:NN \_enumerate_start: \enumerate
\cs_new_eq:NN \_enumerate_stop: \endenumerate
\NewCommandCopy{ \_item_std }{ \item }

% Vars
\int_new:N \g_enumerate_level_int
\int_new:N \g_enumerate_item_int

% Redefine enumerate
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{enumerate}{ }
  {
    \int_gincr:N \g_enumerate_level_int
    \_redefine_item:
    \_enumerate_start:
  }
  {
    \_enumerate_stop:
    \int_compare:nTF { \g_enumerate_level_int = \g_enumerate_item_int }
      { TRUE }{ FALSE }
  }

% Redefine \item
\cs_new_protected:Npn \_redefine_item:
  {
    \RenewDocumentCommand\item{ o }
      {
        \int_gincr:N \g_enumerate_item_int
        %\int_compare:nT { \g_enumerate_level_int > 1 }
          %{
            %\int_gsub:Nn \g_enumerate_item_int { 1 }
          %}
        \tl_if_novalue:nTF {##1}
          {
            \_item_std%[Item ~ \int_use:N \g_enumerate_item_int]
          }
          { \_item_std[##1] }
      }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand\dummy{ m }
  {
    \int_gincr:N \g_tmpb_int
    \texttt{dummy~#1~=~\int_use:N \g_tmpb_int}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Level 1 \dummy{1} OK % \g_enumerate_item_int = 1
  \item Level 1 NO dummy here, dummy in next level
    \begin{enumerate}
      % Start level 2
      \item Level 2 \dummy{2} OK % \g_enumerate_item_int = 2
      \item Level 2 NO dummy here, dummy in next level
        \begin{enumerate}
          % Start level 3
          \item Level 3 \dummy{3} OK % \g_enumerate_item_int = 3
          \item Level 3 NO dummy here, dummy in next level
            \begin{enumerate}
              % Start level 4
              \item Level 4 \dummy{4} OK % \g_enumerate_item_int = 4
              \item Level 4 \dummy{5} OK % \g_enumerate_item_int = 5
            \end{enumerate}
          \item Level 3 \dummy{6} OK % \g_enumerate_item_int = 6
        \end{enumerate}
      \item Level 2 \dummy{7} OK % \g_enumerate_item_int = 7
    \end{enumerate}
  \item Level 1 \dummy{8} OK % \g_enumerate_item_int = 8
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

How can I achieve this?

The real context is a *question/answer* list and the idea is to check that
each question has an answer.

If the line starts with an `\item` and does not open a nested environment
it must have a `\dummy`, if the line starts with an `\item` and opens a
nested environment, each `\item` in the nested environment must have a
`\dummy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `tokcycle` approach, where you wrap your outer environment in `\needdummytrue\tokencyclexpress...\endtokencyclexpress`.  It analyzes the `...` in advance before executing it, and inserts `(MISSING)` into the environment if a `\dummy` was supposed to have appeared on that `\item` but didn't, or an `(XTRA)` if a `\dummy` appeared where it was not expected.

By removing the wrapper, the test goes away and the environment executes normally.

While this MWE does not analyze the "valid form" provided by the OP, this approach was run with that input and does not detect any errors, as expected.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\def\dummy{DD}
\newif\ifneeddummy
\Macrodirective{%
  \ifx\item#1\ifneeddummy\addcytoks{(MISSING)}\else\needdummytrue\fi\fi
  \ifx\end#1\ifneeddummy\addcytoks{(MISSING)}\fi\fi
  \ifx\dummy#1\ifneeddummy\needdummyfalse\else\addcytoks{(XTRA)}\fi\fi
  \ifx\begin#1\ifneeddummy\needdummyfalse\else\addcytoks{(XTRA)}\fi\fi
  \addcytoks{#1}%
}
\begin{document}
\needdummytrue\tokencyclexpress
\begin{itemize}
\item \dummy
\item no dummy
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item \dummy
  \item no dummy
  \item \dummy
  \end{enumerate}
\item \dummy \dummy
\item \dummy
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item \dummy
  \end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}
\endtokencyclexpress
\end{document}
```

[image]

If I comment out the wrapper lines, I get the same output with the diagnostic messages removed.  Of course, the output may contain errors, if the warnings of running the diagnostic were not heeded.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution (has not failed my tests) and fits what I need :)

```
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
% Copy macros
\cs_new_eq:NN \_enumerate_start: \enumerate
\cs_new_eq:NN \_enumerate_stop: \endenumerate
\NewCommandCopy{ \_item_std }{ \item }

% Vars
\int_new:N \g_enumerate_tempa_int
\int_new:N \g_enumerate_tempb_int
\int_new:N \g_enumerate_tempc_int
\int_new:N \l_enumerate_level_int
\int_new:N \g_enumerate_count_item_all_int

% Redefine enumerate
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{enumerate}{ }
  {
    \int_incr:N \l_enumerate_level_int
    \_enumerate_start:
    \_redefine_item:
    \int_case:nn{ \l_enumerate_level_int }
      {
        { 2 }{ \int_gincr:N \g_enumerate_tempa_int }
        { 3 }{ \int_gincr:N \g_enumerate_tempb_int }
        { 4 }{ \int_gincr:N \g_enumerate_tempc_int }
      }
  }
  { \_enumerate_stop: }

% Redefine \item
\cs_new_protected:Npn \_redefine_item:
  {
    \RenewDocumentCommand\item{ o }
      {
        \int_gincr:N \g_enumerate_count_item_all_int
        \tl_if_novalue:nTF {##1} { \_item_std } { \_item_std[##1] }
      }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand\dummy{ m }
  {
    \int_gincr:N \g_tmpb_int
    \texttt{dummy~#1~=~\int_use:N \g_tmpb_int}
  }
\NewDocumentCommand\test{ }
  {
   \int_gset:Nn \g_tmpa_int
     {
        \g_enumerate_count_item_all_int - \g_enumerate_tempa_int
      - \g_enumerate_tempb_int - \g_enumerate_tempc_int
     }
   % \int_show:N \g_tmpa_int
    \int_compare:nTF { \g_tmpa_int = \g_tmpb_int }
      { \typeout{TRUE}  }{ \typeout{FALSE} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Level 1 \dummy{1}
  \item Level 1 NO dummy
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item Level 2 \dummy{2}
      \item Level 2 NO dummy
        \begin{enumerate}
          \item Level 3 \dummy{3}
          \item Level 3 NO dummy
            \begin{enumerate}
              \item Level 4 \dummy{4}
              \item Level 4 \dummy{5}
            \end{enumerate}
          \item Level 3 \dummy{6}
        \end{enumerate}
      \item Level 2 NO dummy
        \begin{enumerate}
          \item Level 3 \dummy{7}
          \item Level 3 NO dummy
            \begin{enumerate}
              \item Level 4 \dummy{8}
              \item Level 4 \dummy{9}
            \end{enumerate}
          \item Level 3 \dummy{10}
        \end{enumerate}
      \item Level 2 \dummy{11}
    \end{enumerate}
  \item Level 1 \dummy{12}
  \item Level 1 \dummy{13}
  \item Level 1 NO dummy
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item Level 2 \dummy{14}
      \item Level 2 NO dummy
         \begin{enumerate}
           \item Level 3 \dummy{15}
          \end{enumerate}
       \item Level 2 \dummy{16}
     \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

% TRUE
\test

\end{document}
```